# Do non-Social Trinitarians believe that "begotten" and "proceeding" are different?

Tags: trinity, persons-of-the-trinity, nicene-creed

(To clarify, I am asking about Nicene-affirming Trinitarians, just ones that don't accept intra-Godhead emotions)

In the Nicene creed, Jesus is described as: *begotten* of the Father

While the Holy Ghost is described as: who *proceedeth* from the Father [and the Son]

How do non-Social Trinitarians consider these different terms as manifesting in the persons of God?

Comment: Huh. I’ve never heard of “non-social” before.

Comment: What are "intra-Godhead emotions"?

Comment: @LukeHill "non-social" isn't what was meant, it's non [Social Trinitarians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_trinitarianism).

Comment: @curiousdannii huh. Still haven’t heard of that before.

Comment: @SupportiveDante the idea that God simplicity rejects the e.g. Father loving the Son pre-incarnation.